# Desktop Mac OSX b10.9, MAIL PROGRAM

Tags: applications, email

When I attach a document to my email, it can come out as an icon, or sometimes as a printed document. Can I control this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are attaching something in a new email:

RIGHT Click on the attachment and select View as Icon or View in Place.

[image: attachment]